# This site can’t be reached when deployed Node app in Rancher

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes, rancher

I'm new to Kubernetes and Rancher. I have builde node docker image with below commands:

```
FROM node:10
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json /usr/src/app
RUN npm cache clean
RUN npm install
COPY . /usr/src/app
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm","start"]
```

I have put docker image to my repo on docker hub.
From Docker hub I'm pulling same image on Rancher/Kubernetes its showing as it as in Active state, as shown below:

> kubectl get svc -n nodejs

```
NAME                      TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)           AGE

node-front-end            ClusterIP   10.43.14.96    <none>        49160/TCP         21m
node-front-end-nodeport   NodePort    10.43.171.52   <none>        49160:31366/TCP   21m
```

But when I'm trying with above IP and Port it's giving message : "This site can’t be reached"

So i'm not able to understand what I'm doing wrong here.

Please guide.

Answer (score 2):

> But when I'm trying with above IP and Port it's giving message : "This site can’t be reached"

Correct, those `ClusterIP`s are "virtual," in that they exist only inside the cluster. The address you will want to use is *any* of the `Node`'s IP addresses, and then the port `:31366` listed there in the `Service` of type `NodePort`.

Just in case you don't already know them, one can usually find the IP address of the Nodes with `kubectl get -o wide nodes`.

Comment: Hi Matthew, I tried using Node IP but no luck. However I tried one simple tutorial from : https://rancher.com/managing-kubernetes-workloads-with-rancher-2-0/. After following first two steps , and trying to access site in same way as mentioned article its still same message "This site can’t be reached"

Comment: Well that's highly unexpected; can you update your question with the output of `curl -v http://${node_ip}:31366` so we can stop using the browser's "friendly" error messages?

Comment: Hi Matthew, It's stating Connection Refused

Comment: That is not the same as posting the output from running `curl -v`, so I hope someone with more psychic abilities can help you

Comment: Hi Matthew, Issue was related to SSL certificate, it got solved after adding right Certificate.